# How to get frame of image when using MKNetworkKit setImageFromURL?

Tags: iphone, ios, mknetworkkit

I am trying to get the size of an image after it is downloaded using setImageFromURL:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIImageView setDefaultEngine:appDelegate.imageCache];
[img setImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testurl.com/testimg.jpg"]];
//img.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0, img.image.size.width, img.image.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

I'm using MKNetworkKit -- is there a way to add a completion handler to the setImageFromURL method?

Comment: It may be dangerous to take any size downloaded.. is their no imageFromURL method? It would seem that you would wan't to check information about the image before assigning it..

Comment: Means You want to image height and width after Getting image from URL?

Comment: Fortunately (in this case) I am in control of the images.  I'm not going to hard code image sizes (in case I build things to be larger/smaller/have a different aspect ratio) but I'd still like this to be as automated as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by adding this line:

```
 self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fetchedImage.size.width, fetchedImage.size.height);
```

to UIImageView+MKNetworkKitAdditions.m:

```
if(imageCacheEngine) {
    self.imageFetchOperation = [imageCacheEngine imageAtURL:url
                   size:self.frame.size
      completionHandler:^(UIImage *fetchedImage, NSURL *url, BOOL isInCache) {

        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fetchedImage.size.width, fetchedImage.size.height);

        [UIView transitionWithView:self.superview
                          duration:isInCache?kFromCacheAnimationDuration:kFreshLoadAnimationDuration
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                        animations:^{
                             self.image = fetchedImage;
                           } completion:nil];
          //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:KW_IMAGE_LOADED object:nil];

      } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {

        DLog(@"%@", error);
      }];
  } else {

    DLog(@"No default engine found and imageCacheEngine parameter is null")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply your own **`completion block`**

Few comments, please use **Grand Central Dispatch** to improve code efficiency and multi-core utilization for this kind of situations.

**Example:**

```
- (void) setImageFromUrl:(NSString*)urlString {  

    [self setImageFromUrl:urlString completion:NULL];  
}

- (void) setImageFromUrl:(NSString*)urlString   
              completion:(void (^)(void))completion {  

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{  

        NSLog(@"Starting: %@", urlString);  
        UIImage *avatarImage = nil;   
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  
        NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  
        avatarImage = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];  
        NSLog(@"Finishing: %@", urlString);  

        if (avatarImage) {  
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
                self.image = avatarImage;  
                //Assign the image to ur ImageView.
                //get the image frame from ur ImageView.frame
            });  
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);  
        }  
        else {  
            NSLog(@"-- impossible download: %@", urlString);  
        }  
    });     
}
```

For more details , please visit **[iOS GCD magic](http://www.programdevtips.com/31716/)**